# Neat, little iteration I found

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

This is an iteration I found today that when it be summed gives the series expansion of $e^x$

$$
p_{n+1} = \int p_{n } dx,  p_{0}=1
$$

This iteration above generates each term, when summed together gives:

$$
\sum p_{\infty} = e^x
$$

In not entirely sure what this tells us about the function $e^x$ but in my opinion, it is quite interesting. What do you think, what could this mean?

Comment: You should write something like $p_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^x p_n(t) \ dt$ so that no arbitrary constants appear.  Also, $\sum p_{\infty}$ makes no sense.  You mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(x)$.

Comment: The iteration means
$$f(x)-1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{n+1}(x)
= \int^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{n}(t)dt=\int^xf(t) dt\\
\implies f’(x) = f(x)=e^x
$$

Comment: You've rediscovered Maclaurin series! You can parameterize your iterated function as $ p(k) = \frac{x^k}{k!} $ By multiplying a coefficient to each term, like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n s(n)}{n!}$ you can construct a wide variety of functions, known as analytic functions.

The coefficients: [1,1,1,1...], or s(n)=1 give e^x. s(n)=(-1)^n will give you e^-x. Alternating 0s and 1s will give you the hyperbolic trig functions. You can have a lot of fun with this. One great feature is that shifting the series coefficients left yields a derivative, and shifting them right yields an integral!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (roughly) tells you that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$.  If you assume that $e^x$ has a nicely-converging power series expansion
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k
$$
you may take its derivative and this is still $e^x$:
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kx^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}.
$$
If you want $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$ then you set the $k$th powers equal to each other from before- and after-differentiating, getting
$$
a_k x^k= (k+1)a_{k+1}x^k = \frac{d}{dx}a_{k+1}x^{k+1},
$$
the point being that the $k$th term is the derivative of the $(k+1)$st term.
If you differentiate your integral identity you get $p_{k+1}'=p_k$, which is the same thing.